# How to iterate over a list of directories to check if they still exist after a delete attempt?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am running a script to uninstall a program and to finish the process, I am checking if the applicable directories get deleted as expected. I have the following:

```
D_PATHS = (
    r'C:\ProgramFiles\D1\FolderA',
    r'C:\ProgramFiles\D1\FolderB',
    r'C:\ProgramFiles\D1\FolderC',
)

for path in D_PATHS:
    self.info('Deleting %s', path)
    if os.path.exists:
        warnings.warn(f'The following directory still exists: {path}')
    else:
        print(f'Removed all required directories')
```

When I run the script, it always throws the warning that the directories still exist, even if they don't. What am I doing wrong? Please excuse my very limited knowledge of coding. I know there's probably an easy answer that I am not understanding.

Comment: It may be possible that you dont have the permission

Comment: You forgot the brackets and the parameter. `os.path.exists(path)`

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.exists` is a function, you need to give it an argument:

```
...
if os.path.exists(path):
    print("Still exists")
...
```

Comment: I tried it with a function and it's still telling me that the directories exist even though they don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a warning for each directory that exists, then you should set a boolean flag to decide at the end whether to print the "removed all required directories" message.

```
    dirs_exist = False
    for path in D_PATHS:
        self.info('Deleting %s', path)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            warnings.warn(f'The following directory still exists: {path}')
            dirs_exist = True
    if not dirs_exist:
        print(f'Removed all required directories')
```

The alternative, if you only want to warn about the *first* directory that still exists, is to `break` from the `for` loop, in which case you can use an `else` clause on your `for` loop for printing the message if no `break` was encountered:

```
    for path in D_PATHS:
        self.info('Deleting %s', path)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            warnings.warn(f'The following directory still exists: {path}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'Removed all required directories')
```

Note that despite the messages saying "Deleting", the code that you have shown here is not actually deleting anything. Presumably you have done so earlier in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you dont have the permission so you can not delete them.

1.Generate a python.exe with pyinstaller .

2.Right Click and click the option "run as administrator"

Comment: I verified manually that the delete script works correctly because the directories do get deleted as expected.